# Find a range of values to subset the rows to maximize the objective function

Tags: optimization, combinatorics, search

I have searched around for some time but couldn't find a similar example to my problem.

It looks common enough that I would expect it to be solved. It lies between search and optimization/regression.

The goal is to find a range of values for each feature, so that the subset of rows where every feature falls in the corresponding range maximizes the objective function.

Assume we have a matrix with Yi and corresponding set of features Xi (say around 40).
Number of samples relatively large, 100k+.

[image]

So for the total data $\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i = 73$ and the average $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i}{n} = 6.0833$

The problem is to:

$\max \sum(Yi) subj $ to:

$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i}{n} > 7$

$n > 5000$

may be more constraints on Yi (does it matter?)

To me it looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning   with additional constraints/objective function being a function of the splits/subsets.

The answer will be subset of the initial matrix with required conditions on the features (A, B, C) to partition original matrix. We can find it using exhaustive search, ie break every feature in the unique bins (or deciles etc) ( (A<=0 or A<=1), (B<1, B<2, B<2.5) ,..) and just go through all combinations of those but then it is not feasible to go through the whole features set.

Right now I think the way to proceed is to create function $f(x)$ where parameters are used to subdivide features space $f(x) = (sum(y_i),count(n),average(y_i)) $ where $i$ are from the subset where $x_1<x1, x_2<x2, ..  $

Then use Bayesian optimization of $f(x)$ to find optimal set of splitting vector $x_j$.

For now I have implemented fitness function that calculate objective ($sum$) as a function of splitting variables $x_1,x_2,x_3...$ that I use to subset the matrix using $<$ condition. Will try to use $>$ condition as well so then can isolate the region for every variable better.

Fitness function also has constraints inside that return $obj value$ of 0 if constraints are breached. So the shape of the fitness function is smooth in the relatively wide region and then can collapse to 0 if constraints are reached.

Has tried 5-6 packages in R so far, pso was slow, BayesOpt was slow and inconsistent, CMA-ES couldn't find a solution. I wonder if it is because derivative didn't exist where constraints were breached?

DEoptim in R looks the best so far, relatively fast and consistent.

Library/solution can be anything, Python/R or OR-Tools etc.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  What are the variables that we are allowed to change, to find the maximum? What is meant by "a matrix with Yi"?  Why isn't Sum(Yi) a fixed value (it's a constant, whatever is the sum of all the Yi values), so why does it make sense to maximize it?  What does "etc." mean?  It seems like the Xi's are irrelevant; do they affect the solution in any way?  Please don't make us guess what the problem statement is.  I encourage you to [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: Hopefully it is clearer now, thanks for the comments

Comment: What does "required conditions" mean?  Can we choose any subset of the rows?  Or are there some restrictions about what subsets we can choose?  If so, what exactly are those restrictions?

Comment: Yes, potentially we can choose any subsets but ideally it is just a block with 2 conditions > and < on (some) variables (of course not every variable has to be a splitting one).  I think that should be enough.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning smth similar to this but with custom constraints/objective function being function of the subset.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand that answer. Do you want us to maximize  the sum or not?    "Ideally" makes  no sense to me here.  Either you want to find the subset that maximizes the sum, or you want something else.  If you want something else, you'll need to clearly state what it is you want. (Maybe your objective function has some additional terms that depend on which  subset was chosen and the number of conditions required to express it?)  If you can't formulate the problem in a way that we can't understand, we have no possibility of finding a solution for you.

Comment: Yes, the objective is to maximize the sum of the values of $Yi$. "Ideally" was in relation to the features split. Theoretically solution can have several split of the features, ie -100< A < -50 and 0 < A < 25 but ideally it is just one subset as I think Yi should be smooth w.r.t. to  features. Regression trees can have several splits on each feature but I would like to avoid it here.

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining well.  If you want us to maximize the sum of the Yi, the "ideally" is irrelevant.  Alternatively, if you have two goals (1) maximize the sum, (2) minimize the number of conditions, then now you have a multi-objective optimization problem.  As such the problem is not yet well-specified and can't be solved yet, because you haven't told us how to trade off between those two goals.  The subset that maximizes the sum might require many conditions.  Subsets that use fewer conditions might yield a lower sum.  So how to choose?

Comment: Normally you must pick a *single* objective function that you want to maximize, and you need to define this objective function to capture both of your goals as well as how you want to trade them off.  Or, you need to impose some hard constraints/requirements (e.g., the subset is defined by at most 3 conditions) -- ones that are required, not just "ideally".  In its current form, this is not yet formulated as a well-posed problem that can be solved.

Comment: Got you, indeed you are right. So the objective is to maximize the sum with only two conditions per feature (one is '>' and another is '<').

Comment: OK.  Please [edit] the question to state that, and to clarify what is meant by "two conditions per feature".  Does this mean that the goal is to find a range of values for each feature, so that the subset of rows where every feature falls in the corresponding range maximizes the objective function?